# Move and delete all files matching grep in folder

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

This command:

```
find buffer/ | grep -i $varname
```

returns a list of file names. I want to zip each of them into individual zip files and

- save these zipped files to a folder `output/` (but with each file having the same name as the original, except for the extension which should be `.zip`)
- delete the original files (the ones responding to     `find buffer/ | grep -i $varname`)

## Edit (@Cyrus):

I have been banging at this for 20 minutes, this is the best I could come up with:

```
find buffer/ | grep -i $varname -exec zip "output/"'{}'.zip '{}' \;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a job for [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
find buffer/ | grep -i "$varname" | xargs -n1 -I{} -- zip "output/{}.zip" {}
```

For `varname=""` and a folder `buffer` created like this:

```
mkdir buffer
touch buffer/1 buffer/2
```

The command will execute:

```
zip output/buffer/1.zip buffer/1
zip output/buffer/1.zip buffer/2
```

Probably you would want to remove the `buffer` part from the filename, we can use `sed 's#^buffer/##'` for that. We can instruct find to list only files with `-type f`. So the following:

```
find buffer/ -type f | grep -i "$varname" | sed 's#buffer/##' | xargs -n1 -I{} -- zip "output/{}.zip" buffer/{}
```

will execute:

```
zip output/1.zip buffer/1
zip output/2.zip buffer/2
```

To delete the original files, we can do smth like this:

```
find buffer/ -type f | grep -i "$varname" | sed 's#buffer/##' | xargs -n1 -I{} -- bash -c 'zip "output/{}.zip" buffer/{}; rm "buffer/{}"'
```

If you want to iterate over the files and do smth more advanced you can use a [while read line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice):

```
find buffer/ -type f | grep -i "$varname" | sed 's#buffer/##' \
| while read -r line; do 
    zip output/${line}.zip buffer/${line}
    rm buffer/${line}
done
```